# Disable plugin not present in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, devops

For some strange reason, the option to disable plugin is not present in jenkins. I had installed this plugin - github-checks. I know that there is a workaround wherein I can add a jpi file to disable plugin but I guess it will still be visible in the UI.

What is the easiest option possible?
[image]

Comment: Could you post the error text as TEXT pls?

Comment: Have you upgraded the other plugins, mentioned in the error, it seems your plugin depends on them?

Comment: Plugins can be disabled from the UI (or by touch $JENKINS_HOME/plugins/$PLUGIN_NAME.jpi.disabled (or $JENKINS_HOME/plugins/$PLUGIN_NAME.hpi.disabled) file.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no need to disable** the plugin, as it cannot be installed in the first place (due to missing dependencies as indicated in the error message). As the plugin is not even installed, you cannot disable it.